# Shell join list of Hosts with list of Ports

Tags: bash, shell, join, ping

I have a List in the format `Host:Port`. From that List I extract all Hosts to be able to run `fping` on it. All Hosts that respond are saved to another file with the according response time `99.194.7.13     : 44.60`.

How I can make a Linux shell script that joins the resulting Host List with the Ports from the `Host:Port` file and the response times in the format `Host:Port time`? Or is there a more efficient way to archieve an online check e.g. with a fping flag that ignores the ports but writes them to a file nevertheless?

I tried with:

```
sed -i 's/:/ /g' hosts.txt
sort -u < hosts.txt > hostss.txt
sort -u < hosts-ports.txt > hosts-portss.txt
join hostss.txt hosts-portss.txt > result.txt
```

The problem with this is that it is rather slow, I get an `is not sorted` error and the ouput has the format `Host : time Port` and not `Host:Port time`.

Sample Input:

```
27.0.0.1:55158
92.168.122.240:80
27.0.0.1:5677
92.168.70.129:1234
107.23.84.102:8080
```

After Ping:

```
92.168.122.240 : 0.16s
27.0.0.1       : 0.27s
```

Expected output:

```
27.0.0.1:55158 0.27s
27.0.0.1:5677 0.27s
92.168.122.240:80 0.16s
```

**Note:** One host in the `Host:Port` file can also have multiple ports assigned to it.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: @choroba Sorry that I didn't add my code right away. I have eddited the question now.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and expected output? If a host is repeated with different ports, how many records does it have in the response file?

Comment: @choroba I added some sample input. I hope this makes it clearer. If one host has e.g. 3 ports in the input file, it is also listed in the output file with 3 ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work with GNU sed:

```
join -t: <(sed 's/ *//g' hosts.txt      | sort -t: -k1,1) \
         <(sed 's/ *//g' hosts-port.txt | sort -t: -k1,1) \
| sed 's/:/ /2'
```

Sort the files by the same criteria you use for joining them (i.e. sort by the first column). The final sed replaces the second colon by a space.

Comment: You mean: _replaces the first two colons by a space_, don't you?

Comment: @user1934428: No. You want to keep the colon between an IP and port.

Comment: So the `2` at the end of the substitution command means the 2nd substitution, not the first 2? I tried to verify this using the `sed` man page, but could not see an explanation for this syntax. I just found in _sed_ tutorials that we can put there the letter *g* for global and *I* for case-insensitive substitution.

Comment: The GNU sed comes with an "info" documentation, the manual is just a short summary. Run `info sed` to browse it.

Comment: Thank you! Found the description needed.